# Unable to access kubernetes Dashboard running on AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, kubernetes

I am new to `Kubernetes` cluster setup. I have a Kubernetes setup running on `AWS EC2` instance with `RHEL 8`. I had tried to access Kubernetes dashboard via localhost but its not working.

1.I had setup kubernetes cluster on AWS EC2 Instance using kubeadm.
2.I am able to deploy pods in the cluster.
3.Deployed Kubernetes dashboard and trying to access it via localhost and from outside but i am not getting the dashboard login window.
4.Tried with cluster IP,changed to NodePort and LoadBalancer.
5.Able to run kubectl proxy and getting kubectl cluster-info.

Please anyone guide me how to deploy and access kubernetes dashboard from AWS EC2 Instance.

Thanks in Advance

```
[root@managernode ~]# cat kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: Reconcile
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-admin
  namespace: kube-system

[root@managernode ~]# kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system
NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
calico-kube-controllers-564b6667d7-qglhj   1/1     Running   0          22h
calico-node-4cpv9                          1/1     Running   0          22h
coredns-5644d7b6d9-c8vj4                   1/1     Running   0          22h
coredns-5644d7b6d9-l8qft                   1/1     Running   0          22h
etcd-managernode                           1/1     Running   0          22h
kube-apiserver-managernode                 1/1     Running   0          22h
kube-controller-manager-managernode        1/1     Running   0          22h
kube-proxy-fhfk7                           1/1     Running   0          22h
kube-scheduler-managernode                 1/1     Running   0          22h
kubernetes-dashboard-7c54d59f66-gvslw      1/1     Running   0          22h

[root@managernode ~]# kubectl proxy
Starting to serve on 127.0.0.1:8001
```

Comment: You have just said access the Kubernetes dashboard is not working and shown some command outputs where nothing seems wrong. Perhaps you could provide some details concretely of what you tried to do, what result you observed, and what you expected. Right now, no one will be able to help you with your problem based on what you've shared so far.

Comment: Hi Amit Kumar thank you for responding.Here i am using AWS EC2 Instance.where i setup the cluster with two worker nodes.now I am trying to expose kubernetes dashboard and access it from my host machine and its not happening.unable to access using Ec2 instance public ip or localhost.im getting the site cant be reached,Please let me know what are the information you needed so that i can update here.

Comment: Provide some details concretely of what you tried to do, what result you observed, and what you expected. Did you run `curl` or open a browser? What address did you `curl` or put in your browser? What was the result displayed in your browser or the output of the `curl` command?

Comment: I had setup kubernetes cluster on AWS EC2 Instance using kubeadm.I am able to deploy pods in the cluster.Deployed Kubernetes dashboard and trying to access it via localhost and from outside but i am not getting the dashboard login window.Tried with cluster IP,changed to NodePort and LoadBalancer.Able to run kubectl proxy and getting kubectl cluster-info.i m expecting dashboard login page but its not happening.Pls assist

Answer (score 0):

Despite service account you need to define cluster role binding:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: eks-admin
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-admin
  namespace: kube-system
```

To make sure you did everything in proper order and follow every steps, read documentation:
[aws-kubernetes-dashboard](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-cluster-kubernetes-dashboard/).

Comment: Hi Maagie appreciate your assistance,yes i had already defined cluster role binding.still i am unable to access dashboard from outside cluster or through localhost,

Comment: Have you tried to setup the dashboard using the documentation linked in the answer? Is it still not working? 

Can you try using this tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/dashboard-tutorial.html

Comment: apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1 is deprecated and use apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1 instead